# Javascript Optimization - Facing issues of slow GUI

Tags: javascript, performance, cgi, webserver

I am working on web app in which I am using javascript on client side to handle validation/calling backend cgi scripts etc kind of things.Now my problem is the WebGUI has become some what slow than it was earlier.Actually everything is working fine as expected but this issue.
I know that there may be many issues which are directly affecting the speed of application.
After all all the application is depended on cgi script response but still is it possible to make the app faster by taking care of certain javascript functions?? 
So can you please suggest that what are the steps I should take care to make javascript execution some what faster ???(i.e less number of LOC)
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Make sure the server sending the response is fast, and give more details about yout JS

Comment: I am using XHR and ajax/jquery calls to send request to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do not post some js code, it will be kind of difficult to help you.
Still, speaking in general: Keep your DOM-Manipulations to a minimum, especially when dealing with lots of data. Do not use jquery functions that affect the dom (append, insertBefore, insertAfter) in a loop - try to do all your preparation in a loop and then call DOM-affecting functions once having all the changes together.
But of course, i do not know if this is the case in any code of your application.

Comment: Thanks for Reply !!! I am getting what you want to convey.I have just one doubt that is you told DOM-affecting functions.I have certain functionality in which I need to insert the dom elements dynamically.Can this thing affect the response time ?

Comment: if by `response time` you mean the time your ajax-calls need to be responed to, then no. This cannot be affected by DOM-Manipulation, only by network and server problems. I was thinking of this problem, because you were also speaking about WebGUI (User Interface) - but if the source of your problems is the response time of the server to ajax calls, then it has to be a server side - problem.